# Why won't popUpMenu show on KeyEvent?

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I have a video view  that is full screen and would like to trigger a popupMenu when a certain key is pressed.  The log shows that the key event is captured, but the popup view will not show. Any ideas why?

```
 @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode , KeyEvent event ){
      switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            Log.i("POP uP MENU","Show");
            mVideoView.pause();
            showPopupMenu(new View(VideoPlayer.this));


        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            popupMenu.dismiss();


      }
      return true;
  }


private void showPopupMenu(View v){
       popupMenu = new PopupMenu(VideoPlayer.this, v);


   if(bitRates != null){
          for(int i=0;i<bitRates.size();i++){
              int menuItem = i;
              popupMenu.getMenu().add(0,menuItem, 0,qualityList.get(i)+" : "+bitRates.get(i));

          }
      }
  popupMenu.show(); 
  popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

   public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
       progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoPlayer.this, "", "Loading video...");

       final int position = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
       new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try{


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            play(streamUrls.get(item.getItemId()),position); 
                        }
                    });


                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }.start();

       return true;

   }
  });
```

}

Comment: Never mind solved the issue.. thanks.

Comment: Care to share how you fixed it?

Comment: @Joeblackdev  , yeah it seems that KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER is an event that is set to be triggered by the VideoView by default. So when I pressed that key VideoView triggered its event event instead of the event I was requesting it to. I changed the KeyEvent KEYCODE to another key(One not used by Videoview) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that

```
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER
```

is an event that is set to be triggered by the **VideoView** by default. So when I pressed that key VideoView triggered its event event instead of the event I was requesting it to. I changed the KeyEvent KEYCODE to another key(One not used by Videoview) and it worked.